# Do other frameworks have something like NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter

`NSNotificationCenter` is a very cool feature for application-level message passing and observation. Is this something exclusive to Cocoa, or do other frameworks make use of this device? Does it derive from an established design pattern?

Comment: `NSNotificationCenter` is not language-specific - it can be implemented in pretty much any non-toy programming language.

Comment: That's not a language feature, but simply a SDK class, meaning you can roll your own in any language

Answer (score 2):

In most frameworks, this is called a Broadcaster.  The general pattern is called Observer, and it's in Design Patterns (the Gang Of Four book).  I think the original appearance was probably in Smalltalk 80, but all modern frameworks facilitate something like this.